# Find a primitive root modulo 250

Tags: number-theory

I know that 250 can be written as 250 = 2*5^3,so using the classification theorem to get the root is what I don't understand.Can anyone give me more insight about the classification theorem and how it can be linked to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly: $250 =2\times 5^3$ **has** primitve roots because it has the form $2p^k\,$ with prime $p$.

To actually compute a primitive root you can use 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots, which essentially says:

> If $(g,n) = 1$, then $g$ is a primitive root of $n$ if and only if $g^{\phi(n)/q} \not \equiv 1 \pmod n$ for every prime divisor $q$ of $\phi(n)$.

Since $\phi(250)=100=2^2\times5^2$ you have to check for a candidate $g$ that
$g^{100/2} \not \equiv 1 \pmod {250}$ and $g^{100/5} \not \equiv 1 \pmod {250}.$

$g=2$ is not relative prime to 250.

Actually $g=3$ is the smallest primitive root because 
$3^{100/2} \equiv 249 \pmod {250}$ and $3^{100/5}  \equiv 124 \pmod {250}.$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $3$ is an odd primitive root of $5$ and $3^{5-1}\equiv 6\not\equiv 1\pmod{5^2}$. Hence $3$ serves as a primitive root for all powers of $5$.

Next consider our specific case $2\cdot 5^3$ :
We have  $\phi(2\cdot 5^3) = \phi(2)\phi(5^3) = \phi(5^3)=100$

Let the order of $3$ modulo $2\cdot 5^3$ be $n$, then 
$$n \mid 100 \tag{1}$$

Also
$$3^{n}\equiv  1\pmod{2\cdot 5^3}  \implies 3^n\equiv  1\pmod{5^3}$$
$$\implies \phi(5^3) = 100\mid n\tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we can conclude $n = 100$, making $3$ a primitive root of $2\cdot 5^3$